# ar-extensions _ne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using [ar-extensions](http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/arext) to extend the ability of doing conditions in ruby on rails.  I am trying to use _ne or _not but it won't work.  I can use _lt or _gt.  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LHS: normal comparison

RHS: equivalent comparison using only < operator

> `A < B :: A < B`
>
> `A > B :: B < A`
>
> `A != B :: A < B || B < A`